# SHA256 hash the body and base64 encode in Python Vs TypeScript

Tags: python, typescript, hmac

My goal is to hash the body in `SHA256` and then encode it with `base64`. I am converting `python` code to `TypeScript`.

Based on google search, what I understood is, `crypto` can be used against `hashlib` and `base64`. Here challenge is, when I use `.createHmac` then it requires the `secret` when in python I can directly work with body. Is it another way to achieve `python` result in `typeScript`?

NOTE: This is the first time I am seeing python code so please correct me if I am missing something here.

**Python Code:**

```
import hashlib
import base64

body = "johnDoe"
abc =  base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha256(body.encode('utf-8')).digest())
print(abc)
```

Output:

```
b'RnuqbBqTNwQ7v3g3tKsVAi+NUALBCUeoRBEq6Yil6RA='
```

This can be verified [here](https://repl.it/repls/FrigidPlumObjects).

**TypeScript Code:** Using `createHmac`

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var secret = "PYPd1Hv4J6";
var body = "johnDoe";

var hmac = crypto.createHmac("sha256",secret);
var hmac_result = hmac.update(body).digest('base64');
console.log(hmac_result);
```

Output:

```
DLZdA1/ULIIECiJ4t+HYDLE+FRPIfcFQNo7Uw/csopU=
```

This can be verified [here](https://repl.it/repls/SpiffyQueasyGlitch).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can achieve this using `createHash`.

**TypeScript Code:**

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var body = "johnDoe";

var hash = crypto.createHash("sha256");
var hash_result = hash.update(body, 'utf8').digest('base64');
console.log(hash_result);
```

Output:

```
RnuqbBqTNwQ7v3g3tKsVAi+NUALBCUeoRBEq6Yil6RA=
```

This can be verified [here](https://repl.it/repls/ImpartialNeglectedClasslibrary).