# What is hmac.new equivalent in node.js?

Tags: python, node.js, typescript, node-crypto

I want to `HMAC SHA256` hash the normalized request using the client secret and base64 encode the result. I am getting different result in `python` and `typeScript`. My goal is to achieve `python` result in `typeScript`. How to do that?

I was able to convert `hashlib.sha256` ([Here is my approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56153113/sha256-hash-the-body-and-base64-encode-in-python-vs-typescript)) to `typeScript` equivalent but not sure about `hmac.new`

**Python Code:**

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64

request = "Hello World";
secret = "MySecret"

requestBytes = bytes(request.encode('utf-8'))
secretBytes = bytes(secret.encode('utf-8'))
hmacConversion = hmac.new(secretBytes, requestBytes, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
signature = base64.b64encode(hmacConversion)
print(signature)
```

Output:

```
b'm4nZSWE3Y/tPXToy/0cJMGpR2qpsXgCnF3tsSiZtYt0='
```

[Sample Code](https://repl.it/repls/FirstBruisedQuote)

**TypeScript Code:**

```
var secret = "Hello World";
var body = "MySecret";

var hmac = crypto.createHmac("sha256", secret)
                 .update(Buffer.from(body, 'utf-8'))
                 .digest('hex');
console.log(hmac);


var hmac2 = crypto.createHmac("sha256", secret)
                 .update(body, 'utf-8')
                 .digest('hex');
console.log(hmac2);
```

Output:

```
f1f157335b0982cbba94290163d61582a87352817788b793238817dd631c26d4
```

[Sample Code](https://repl.it/repls/ImpishSubtleMicrobsd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. This is very silly mistake where I spent 1 day. Hope this would save someone's day.

**Code:**

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

// Below was silly mistake. In my question those parameters are swapped.
var body = "Hello World"; 
var secret = "MySecret";

var hmac = crypto.createHmac("sha256", secret )
                 .update(body)
                 .digest('base64')
console.log(hmac);
```

Output:

```
m4nZSWE3Y/tPXToy/0cJMGpR2qpsXgCnF3tsSiZtYt0=
```

[Sample Code](https://repl.it/repls/DistantKnowledgeableExtension)